# Typeahead loader not working despite passing the relevant state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, typeahead, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I want to add either a loader or a simple text something like 'Searching...' whenever a user presses a button on the Search field but am unable to do so. Here is the code:

```
    fetchingDataOnChange = () => {
    let nameValue = this.state.searchName;
    var myParams = {
        nameValue: nameValue
    }
    axios.post('/get-hcp-data', myParams)
        .then((res) => {
            const hcps = res.data;
            this.setState({ isLoading: true })
            console.log('State before loading data: ', this.state);
            this.setState({ hcps: hcps, hcpName: Object.values(hcps.hcp_details_concat) })
            console.log('HCP Data values on typeahead: ', 
            Object.values(this.state.hcps.hcp_details_concat));
            console.log(res);
            this.setState({ isLoading: false })
            console.log('State after loading data: ', this.state);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

   <Typeahead
       id="basic-example"
       options={this.state.hcpName}
       placeholder="Search by Name..."
       emptyLabel={this.state.isLoading ? "Searching..." : ''}
       isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
       onInputChange={(searchName) => this.setState({ searchName }, this.fetchingDataOnChange)}
    />
```

As you can see, I also tried console logging and the state is changing appropriately but both the emptyLabel and isLoading functionality is not working. Any reasons?

The data is being fetched but the loader part isn't working.

Comment: I think `emptyLabel` expects `node` but what you are returning is `string`. Check out the docs `https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/API.md#typeahead`

Comment: So what should I add there if I want to display 'Searching...' ?

Comment: You’re setting your loading states after the request has already finished. Try moving `this.setState({ isLoading: true })` to before you make the request. Then once the request finishes, toggle to false.